# Redirect to URL after form post

Tags: php, forms, url, post, redirect

I have a problem which i can't resolve. I want to redirect to an URL after i do a form post (button clicked). How can i do that? I didn't find a solution so far on the internet.

My files:

addmatch.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Date: <input type="text" name="date">
Home: <input type="text" name="home">
Away: <input type="text" name="away">
Result: <input type="text" name="result">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

define("HOST", "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "..");
define("PASS", "..");
define("DB", "..");

$con=mysqli_connect(HOST, DBUSER, PASS, DB);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO wedstrijden (date, home, away, result)
VALUES
('$_POST[date]','$_POST[home]','$_POST[away]','$_POST[result]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use header('Location: ur_path');

Comment: People use javascript to do that. Use somethin like `window.location.assign("your-url-goes-here")`

Comment: @zander It's down to the individual situation, sometimes PHP might be more appropriate. I.E. Javascript can be disabled.

Comment: Ooh then header(..) should do

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) against.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I can see now, you form will send post request to insert.php
if you want to redirect user after you will save data in database you should add header("location youUrl.php"); before any output (echo, print etc)